# Why does this usage of thread_local crash?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, thread-local-storage

I have reduced the problem to the following small code snippet:

```
struct tls {
    ~tls() {}
    void dont_opt_out() {}
};

thread_local tls tls_obj;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    tls_obj.dont_opt_out();
}
```

When executed the program crashes. Why?

I'm using gcc version 4.8.2 on Windows, I compile with `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp`.

Comment: Works on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd105c040c971bd1) and [IDEone](http://ideone.com/GxxmPu) GCC 4.8.1…

Comment: @Potatoswatter coliru is linux - this is on Windows.

Comment: It's a data point. It looks like the Windows runtime library is broken. By the way, what is the nature of the crash?

Comment: I don't use Windows myself but in Linux you need to enable threading by passing -pthread to the compiler command line. I wonder if Windows requires something similar...

Comment: Works for me using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 4.8.2` and using a recent trunk of mingw-w64 (CRT). Admittedly this is a cross compiler, but that shouldn't really matter. Successfully executed the result on Win7. You should probably ask the developers of your build or update the CRT if you built the toolchain yourself.

Comment: Run it under the debugger to locate where exactly it crashes.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin I tried but gdb says it received a SIGSEGV in ?? - not very useful (I did compile with `-g` of course). Strangely this bug does not appear when compiling with `-static-libstdc++`.

Comment: @nmaier, which trunk are you using? I'm having the same problem. I'm also using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 4.8.2` and cross compiling on Linux. My program is still crashing when a thread access thread_local storage. @nightcraker, did you manage to solve the problem? thanks.

Comment: @LeonardodeMoura Must have been https://svn.code.sf.net/p/mingw-w64/code/trunk @ r6369 when I tested the question code. PS: Makefile I use to build the cross-compiler itself: https://github.com/nmaier/mingw-w64-make

Comment: @LeonardodeMoura Nope, not yet. Glad to hear I'm not the only one having a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling your code as multi-threaded.

Under Cygwin, it is `-mthreads` option for both compiler and linker.